# No match for call to std::map while using std::map::at

Tags: string, function-pointers, stdmap

I am stuck in problem with std::map function.

My code, in a nutshell, consists of a template base class and within that class, I have a struct like below:

```cpp
template <class DERIVED>
class base 
{
public: 
struct association
{
    bool accept_country{false};
    int(DERIVED::*fp)(const std::string country);
}

// The class have a lot of methods where I get the map, do some logic around and one of them I call the function call_visa in this way 
int another_method(blabla)
{
  ret_fp = base<DERIVED>::call_visa(func_map, name, "Brazil");
}

int call_visa(std::map<std::string, association> *func_map, const std::string& name, std::string country))
{
  return func_map->at(name)(country);
}
```

[...]

Then I have a derived class, like below:

```cpp
class derived : public base<derived>                      
{ 
private:
  std::map<std::string, association> func_map; 
  int visa_renata(std::string country)
  {
    // do_something
    return 0;
  }

public:
  derived()
  {
    cmd_association tmpinit[] = { 
    {true, &derived::visa_renata}};
    func_map["Renata"] = tmpinit[0];
  }
  inline std::map<std::string, association>& getMap() { return func_map;}
```

when I compile the code, I get an error "no match for call to std::map" in the return of the function call_visa.

Does anyone know what I should do to get rid of this error?